# Using Beautiful Soup to scrape text from tags that are not be properly formatted

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm using Beautiful Soup and requests to try and scrape the text information from an html page like the one shown at the bottom of this post. I've tried using

`judge_record = judge_soup.find("div", {"class": "field__item even"})`

and then

`result = judge_record.findAll("br")`

to extract the text in between the `br` tags along with the bold tags.

Unfortunately, when I do this I only get back:

`[<br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br>
Private practice, Washington, D.C., 2003-2006, 2007-2010<br>
Private practice, Atlanta, Georgia, 2006-2007<br>
Assistant U.S. attorney, Northern District of Georgia, 2010-2014<br/></br></br></br>, <br>
Private practice, Atlanta, Georgia, 2006-2007<br>
Assistant U.S. attorney, Northern District of Georgia, 2010-2014<br/></br></br>, <br>
Assistant U.S. attorney, Northern District of Georgia, 2010-2014<br/></br>, <br/>]
[Finished in 1.0s]`

Is this because the `<br>` tags don't have complementary closing tags?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="field field--name-judge-record-display field--type-ds field--label-hidden">
    <div class="field__items">
        <div class="field__item even">Born 1974  in Madison, WI

            <br><br>
            <b>Federal Judicial Service:</b>

            <br> Judge, U.S. District Court for the Middle District of Georgia</br>
            <br>Nominated by Barack Obama on March 11, 2014, to a seat vacated by W. Louis Sands. Confirmed by the Senate on November 18, 2014, and received commission on November 20, 2014. 
            <br><br>
            <b>Education:</b>

            <br> Brown University, B.A., 1997
            <br>Yale Law School, J.D., 2002

            <br><br>
            <b>Professional Career:</b>

            <br>
            <p>Law clerk, Hon. Marvin J. Garbis, U.S. District Court, District of Maryland, 2002-2003
            <br/>


            Private practice, Washington, D.C., 2003-2006, 2007-2010<br />
            Private practice, Atlanta, Georgia, 2006-2007<br />

            Assistant U.S. attorney, Northern District of Georgia, 2010-2014<br />
            </p>


</div>
```

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: @saltchicken I wanted to write each chuck of information to a row of an excel file. I figured I first had to extract everything to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text inside the `div`tag, you can use the [**`get_text()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) function.

```
judge_record = soup.find('div', class_='field__item even')
print(judge_record.get_text(' ', strip=True))
```

Output:

> Born 1974  in Madison, WI Federal Judicial Service: Judge, U.S.
>   District Court for the Middle District of Georgia Nominated by Barack
>   Obama on March 11, 2014, to a seat vacated by W. Louis Sands.
>   Confirmed by the Senate on November 18, 2014, and received commission
>   on November 20, 2014. Education: Brown University, B.A., 1997 Yale Law
>   School, J.D., 2002 Professional Career: Law clerk, Hon. Marvin J.
>   Garbis, U.S. District Court, District of Maryland, 2002-2003 Private
>   practice, Washington, D.C., 2003-2006, 2007-2010 Private practice,
>   Atlanta, Georgia, 2006-2007 Assistant U.S. attorney, Northern District
>   of Georgia, 2010-2014

If you want all the different lines in a list, you can use this:

```
judge_record = soup.find('div', class_='field__item even')
result_text = [x.strip() for x in judge_record.contents if isinstance(x, NavigableString)]
print(result_text)
```

You've to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString` to use this.

Output:

```
['Born 1974  in Madison, WI', '', '', 'Judge, U.S. District Court for the Middle District of Georgia', 'Nominated by Barack Obama on March 11, 2014, to a seat vacated by W. Louis Sands. Confirmed by the Senate on November 18, 2014, and received commission on November 20, 2014.', '', '', 'Brown University, B.A., 1997', 'Yale Law School, J.D., 2002', '', '', '', '']
```

If you don't want the empty lines (`''`), you can use this instead.

```
result_text = [x.strip() for x in judge_record.contents if isinstance(x, NavigableString) and x.strip()]
print(result_text)
```

Output:

```
['Born 1974  in Madison, WI', 'Judge, U.S. District Court for the Middle District of Georgia', 'Nominated by Barack Obama on March 11, 2014, to a seat vacated by W. Louis Sands. Confirmed by the Senate on November 18, 2014, and received commission on November 20, 2014.', 'Brown University, B.A., 1997', 'Yale Law School, J.D., 2002']
```